# Highlight logic of vertex selection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, edit-mode, selection-tools

When I select a vertex in Edit mode, some—but not all—of the edges that terminate at the vertex are highlighted. Moreover, which of the edges are highlighted can vary across a surface.

The image below shows an example. The selected vertices are on the periphery of a hole. Some of the edges highlighted radiate outward from the hole along the outer surface of the part; others point inward along the cylindrical surface of the hole; still others connect adjacent vertices on the periphery of the hole.

[image]

Just wondering: why are only some edges highlighted? Why is a particular edge highlighted and another not? Just trying to understand so that I can better interpret what I see in Edit mode. Thanks!

Comment: Highlight goes to above a half of the edge between selected and connected vertex. If it isn't visible then there's another geometry present there (vertices cutting those edges), like for example on your screenshot there are multiple double vertices, probably loose edges etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, there are no duplicate vertices or loose edges. Also, each vertex connects to more than one vertex, yet only one of the connecting edges is highlighted. This can't be due to some edges being occluded, as I rotated the view in several ways to see if it had an effect... and it didn't... Just trying to understand what is actually going on. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, when you move  a highlighted vertex, do any non-highlighted edges move with it?

Comment: They do not... and I see now that my mesh isn't that clean after all. Blender didn't find any duplicate vertices when I selected the option to remove them, but clearly that is no guarantee that the mesh is free of what are... at least almost... duplicates. Moving the selected vertices exposes what is an almost identical surface directly underneath (meaning coincident with that to which the vertices belong). I created the mesh in CAD, and the software probably doesn't optimize for clean meshes. I'll take the sort of highlighting I described in my post as a sign of a dirty mesh in the future...